# Installing Group Policy Template

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, internet-explorer-8

We're prepping to roll out IE8 to our organisation. I'm trying to figure out how to install the policy template to the W2K3 DC so I can configure the policy options.

I get the feeling that installing IE8 on the DC would do what I need, but I'd prefer not to at this stage. Is there an alternative that also allows me to retain my current policy configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the [IE8 Administration Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=0BE39082-E9C6-4F6B-A38E-CB4E284CF987&displaylang=en) should install the IE8 version of the file you want (inetres.adm) -- or you can grab the file from any machine that has IE8 installed I believe (the file should be identical across platforms -- grab it off your home machine). Copy the file into %windir%/inf/.

Free bonus: [The settings that should be exposed.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ab4655f2-0a3c-42eb-974d-24b2790bf592&displaylang=en&tm)

This [guy](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/rtrent/archive/2009/05/28/add-the-ie8-adm-file-to-available-gpos.aspx) seems to have made a cute little installer that installs the same inetres.adm file that my server has for IE8 (based on MD5 check).  He also has the ADM file available, which you could open in NOTEPAD/Wordpad/Your favorite text editor to confirm its nothing malicious.  YourMilageMayVary on this one.

> I get the feeling that installing IE8 on the DC would do what I need

Correct -- that would also install the inetres.adm for IE8.

Comment: That looks great, thanks, but when I do that will my existing IE6 policy settings be retained?